# How to detect which image has been tapped in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have created 6 UIImageViews on a ViewController, and I am later going to add TapGestureRecognizers to all of them.

I want to make it so that depending on what image has been clicked, another ViewController will open and display certain information.

For this to happen, I need to know which image has been clicked. How would I do this in Swift?

Comment: Or you can do it the old-fashoned way and put transparent buttons over each.

Comment: I might try that, just put the buttons over then check the image that the button is over. Thanks!

Comment: Unless there is another way?

Comment: can't you tag each view or button?

Answer (score 6):

UIGestureRecognizer has property 'view' this property is the view you add it to. For this example the imageView.

```
func tap(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    println(gesture.view!.tag) // You can check for their tag and do different things based on tag
}

let img = UIImageView()
img.userInteraction = true
img.tag = 0
img.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(self, action: "tap:"))
```

Comment: @Arbitur Would like to ask noob question. I have a UITableView with repeating cells having UIImage in it. For the `img.tag = 0`, how do I then get the selected cell of that selected image?