# How to distinguish which item has been selected in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a project similar to Instagram. When you select user, it brings you to user VC. When you select comment, it brings you to comment VC.

I have a custom UITableViewCell that has many items in it just like Instagram as mentioned above. What I'm trying to achieve is when user selects any item within a UITableViewCell regardless it is a label, or image, it will do segue to another VC for detailed information.

I'm referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958745/how-to-detect-which-image-has-been-tapped-in-swift) to achieve it, but my concern is how am I going to recognise which has been selected? Because I have an unknown repetitive count of rows.

I don't really need codes as they can most likely be found with thorough searching, though it would be more helpful. But I just need structure because I'm totally lost on how I should do this.

I'm doing this in Swift programming.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Which item in the row? Or was the item in row 1 or row 2?

Comment: i need to know which item was selected in which row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert `UIButton`s into `UITableViewCell`s. Those `UIButton`s won't conflict with the `UITableViewCell`s tap gesture. I would subclass `UIButton` so you could pass that row and item data to that button when created

Comment: I could replace my labels with buttons. But what about the `UIImage`s that I have? I'm trying to avoid using buttons to add an image to it.

Comment: You can still do it with `UIImageView` or `UILabel`, you just need to add gesture recognizers to them, that's what's nice about UIButton is all of that is already taken care of for you. You can set the UIButton with a background image as well.

Comment: I'm doing what you are saying now. Inside UITableViewCell, I create tapped gesture for an UIImage. I could print out image, however in my tap gesture method, `print(self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow)` it is showing nil. Could my understanding of what you are saying is wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need to subclass `UIImageView` and add some attributes to it like `indexPath` and `item` so when the UIImageView gets tapped you can extract those values from the image view, not the table view cell. The table view cell is not getting selected in this instance since you have an image view that is getting selected

Comment: Ok got it. I'm using `tag` instead. So I add `indexPath.row` inside my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so there will be different tags at different cells! Got what I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"abc" sender:self];
    }

    if (indexPath.row==1)
    {

    }
   }
```